# jQuery Masked Bugs on Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking, maskedinput

I'm trying to use jQuery Mask Plugin https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ in order to create masks for things like license plates and the like.

It works fine on desktop no problems there, the problem comes when I try to use an Android device instead, it wont allow me to type more than 1 character... it works fine for numbers, but not characters

```
$("#vehiclePlate").mask("AA-AA-AA", {
   autoclear: false
});
```

I made a little jsFiddle with a basic example of what I'm trying to do, 
https://jsfiddle.net/043gqn3f/1/ when I try that on Android it fails and won't allow me to type my characters, yet it works fine on Desktop... Does anyone have any idea what's going on?